# PHAssetCreationRequest supportsAssetResourceTypes

Tags: ios, photo, photokit

I tried to write a live photo to album. It always failed. So I tested on my iPhone7, I found

```
BOOL s = [PHAssetCreationRequest supportsAssetResourceTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:PHAssetResourceTypePairedVideo], nil]];
```

always return NO.

It's so weird, does anyone encounter this before?

Answer (score 0):

I think what it means is that creating an asset with *only* a PairedVideo type is not supported. But if you pass an array with both PairedVideo and Photo then it should return YES.